# Not set error in php in a login script about sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a problem in the session in php, while my login script and my database connection is ok and when the user is login it goes ok, but using the session it "says that is not set".Here is my code about **login.php**: 
email is:one@gmail.com, password is:12345678

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['log'])){


    include "database.php";

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pas'];


$query="SELECT * from users WHERE email='{$email}'  AND pass='{$pass}'";
$rezultat=mysqli_query($db,$query);

if(!$rezultat){
    echo "Failed";
}



$nr=mysqli_num_rows($rezultat);
if($nr==1){

$_SESSION['email'];
header('Location:menu.php');


}

else{
    echo "invalid";
}


}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">

Email<input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password<input type="password" name="pas"><br>

<input type="submit" name="log" value="Log in">
</form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my code about **menu.php** where i direct the user if the credentials are ok, like they are in database. There is only one row in phpmyadmin and the email is:one@gmail.com, password is:12345678

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<?php


if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){

    echo $_SESSION['email'];
}

else{
    echo "not set";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're not going live with this, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Just before you use the `header` to redirect you simply have `$_SESSION['email'];` and do not set any value to it.

```
$_SESSION['email'];#<!-- no value -->
header('Location:menu.php');
```

So I guess something like

```
$nr=mysqli_num_rows($rezultat);
if($nr==1){

    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $rezultat );

    $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
    header('Location:menu.php');

    /* or, $_SESSION['email']=$email */

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your login.php if the credentials are OK set the value to  variable in the session as:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```